# Como usar uma variável dentro de outro método da mesma class?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Como eu poderia usar no método ***define_title()*** a variável `$extension` que está dentro do método ***file_verify***?

```
class Title extends Imoveis
{
    public function file_verify($file)
    {
        $file       = explode("/", $file);
        $file       = $file[1];
        $extension  = pathinfo($file);
        $extension  = $extension['extension'];
    }

    public function define_title()
    {
        if(isset($extension) && $extension == 'php')
        {
            return "Bingooooooo";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Tu estás a utilizar `OOP` lembra-te de quais opções melhor assentam quando vais resolver problemas de escopo.

```
class Title extends Imoveis
{
    private $extension;     
    public function file_verify($file)
    {       
        $file       = explode("/", $file);
        $file       = $file[1];
        $extension  = pathinfo($file);
        $this->extension  = $extension['extension'];
    }

    public function define_title()
    {
        if(isset($this->extension) && $this->extension == 'php')
        {
            return "Bingooooooo";
        }
    }
}
```